# Finding order of $gag^{-1}$ in $G$ if $a^2=e\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group, the order of $G$ is even, let $a \in G$, $a^2=e$

> I need to find the order of $gag^{-1}$ in $G$

**My attempt:**

$(gag^{-1})^2=(gag^{-1})(gag^{-1})=ga(g^{-1}g)ag^{-1}=ga(e)ag^{-1}=ga^2g^{-1}=g(e)g^{-1}=e$

$\Rightarrow$ the order of $gag^{-1}=\boxed{\color{blue}2}$

Is it correct? is there other why to solve this? any **hints** please?

Comment: correct............ unless $a=e$

Comment: The correct conclusion is:  the order of $gag^{-1}$ divides $2$.

Comment: More generally, the map: $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is a group automorphism, so...

Comment: You need to prove that $gag^{-1}\neq 1$ to prove that it is of order $2$.

Comment: Be careful! Saying $a^2 = e$ is *not the same thing* as saying the order of $a$ is $2$. For example, the identity satisfies $e^2 = e$, but only has order $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just restating what others have already said in the comments..

You have two cases. Case 1 is where $a=e$ is the identity in your group. Here the order of $gag^{-1} = gg^{-1} = e$ is $1$.

Case 2 is where $a\neq e$. Then your calculation above indeed shows that the order is $2$ (because only the identity has order $1$). And, as mentioned below, $gag^{-1}\neq e$ because if it was: $gag^{-1} = e$, then $a = g^{-1}eg = g^{-1}g = e$ (which is case 1).

Comment: Now all I have to do is to prove that $gag^{-1} \neq e$

Comment: Yes, the OP's proof does not show that $gag^{-1}\neq e$ if $a\neq e$.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, conjugate elements (ie elements of the form $gag^{-1}$) have the same order.

Let ord($a$)=$n$.
Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
(gag^{-1})^n &=& gag^{-1}gag^{-1}gag^{-1}...gag^{-1} \\
&=& ga^ng^{-1} \hbox{   by cancelling all the $g^{-1}g$} \\
&=& gg^{-1} \hbox{   as $a^n=e$}\\
&=& e
\end{eqnarray}

which shows that ord($gag^{-1}$) $\leq n=$ ord($a$).

Now let $h=g^{-1}$. By the same argument ord($hgag^{-1}h^{-1}$) $\leq$ ord($gag^{-1}$). But $hgag^{-1}h^{-1}=g^{-1}gag^{-1}g=a$ so we get ord($a$) $\leq$ ord($gag^{-1}$) hence they must have the same order $n$.

Applying this to your question, the order of $gag^{-1}$ is the same as the order of $a$, which divides 2 since $a^2=e$ and is 1 if and only if $a=e$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks - I am so used to conjugation acting like that, I didn't think to check which way round OP had done it. I'll edit it so it is on the other side :)